# How to Read file properties from a zip file ..?

Tags: c#, zip, extract, archive, unzip

I have a zip file and I want to read file properties from this zip file and if file is according to my information Like if I want .doc file and in zip the file is .doc then copy it. And if there is a zip file which contains Folder and that folder contains Zip File and in that zip file there is another folder and then there is required file so how can I get that required file and also save full path of that file.?
and I want to do this in c#.

Comment: More information are required to answer this question

Comment: Just want to know that how to extract file from a multilevel zipped file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) you can read the files in a zip file as easy as:

```
string zipPath = @"c:\example\MyFile.zip";
using (zip archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(zipPath))
{
      foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
      {
          System.Console.WriteLine(entry.);
      }
 }
```

Comment: did this code work for multi level zipped file??? i mean there is a zip file with in zip file and then there is my file... did this code work ??

Comment: For multi level zipped file, I would suggest that you extract the zip file in a temporary location and check for other zip files in the original file. As you haven't provided any kind of code in your question, I propose that you check the [DotNetZip Library](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) to find a specific scenario that matches your needs